# Solutions to manage a list of files for archiving

Tags: file-management, gui, archiving

There is a need to selectively archive files and folders from a volume.

For such purpose there is usually a command line option in archivers that can be used to supply a text file listing of files to archive. Unfortunately, archivers don't have a GUI equivalent of such feature, where you would be able to manage a file listing **before** archiving.

My question is, are there any ways to make managing file listings for later archiving easier, rather than just plain old text editing, maybe something having a file manager interface. I have not been able to Google any solution that fits the need.

---

For now I came up with a following solution. Using [Link Shell Extension or ln.exe](https://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html#hardlinkclones) I create a clone of the parent folder I want to archive, which basically just recreates the target's folder structure and populates it with hard-links to the original files. Then I manage and prepare the clone with a standard file manager applications. And the final step is archiving it with an archiver. There are some disadvantages as well as advantages to this solution, but I'm interested to hear of other possible solutions, on any OS.